# Flex + custom component + design-time + binding

Tags: apache-flex, binding, design-time

I'm trying to create simple custom component with two labels with this MXML:

```
<mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" width="250" height="30">

    <mx:String id="result" />

    <mx:Label x="5" y="7" id="titleLabel" text="{label}" width="120"/>
    <mx:Label x="125" y="7" id="resultLabel" text="{result}" width="120" textAlign="right" color="#A41D00"/>

</mx:Canvas>
```

It is working well at runtime, bud I have troubles making it working at design-time. How can I make databinding work at the design time? If it is impossible, how should I code the label text assignements?

Comment: Can you quantify Design Time?  Do you mean in the Flash Builder Design view?  Or Flash Catalyst?  Or something else?

Comment: It is Flash builder 3.0.

Comment: Why do you want data binding in design view?

Comment: Hello, Amarghosh, I want to add the design time to this component because there would be 10-30 of these components on the page and I need to identify them at design-time. They are used to output the result on the page and of course, I can use two different labels to do the same thing, but I just wanted to learn how to create the design time support...

Answer (score 0):

Try with `text={data.label}` and `text={data.result}` instead of mere `label` and `result`.

Comment: Hello, jasie21,  I've tried your code, but got "{data.label}" message instead of an actual label value...

Answer (score 0):

You won't see the actual data at design time. I'm not exactly sure what you're going for but here's how you might code the Labels

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" width="100%" height="100%">

<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        private var str : String = "Hello world";
    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:Label x="5" y="7" id="titleLabel" text="{str}" width="120"/>
<mx:Label x="125" y="7" id="resultLabel" text="{titleLabel.text}" width="120" textAlign="right" color="#A41D00"/>

</mx:Application>
```